# How to change value of model in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

**EDIT 1**

My code is:

**Modal.ts**

```
import {Component, NgIf, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

declare function initMaterial();

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    directives: [NgIf, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    templateUrl: './frontend/components/modal/modal.html',
    styleUrls: ['./frontend/components/modal/modal.css']
})

export class Modal {
    public isOpen: boolean = false;
    public dtCompromise: Date;

    constructor() {
        this.dtCompromise = new Date();
    }

    open() {
        this.isOpen = true;
        initMaterial();
    }

    close() {
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
}
```

**Modal.html**

```
<div class="card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp modal" *ng-if="isOpen">
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Novo compromisso</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <form action="#">
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="date" [(ng-model)]="dtCompromise"/>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dtCompromisse">Data</label>
            </div><br>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                <textarea class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" rows= "5" [(ng-model)]="dsCompromise"></textarea>
                <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="dsCompromisse">Descrição</label>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" (click)="save($event, dsCompromise, dtCompromise);">
            Salvar <i class="material-icons">save</i>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="close()">
            <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the constructor i tried initialize variable dtCompromise as **this.dtCompromise = new Date();**. But the value is undefined after this. Any sugestion for fix?

**UPDATED**

I discovered what's problem. Angular2 ignore input with type="date". After change type for text works for me. The problem now is. For use one field as date is necessary use datepicker. I use material-design-lite as framework responsive. This not contains datepicker for fix this. Will be necessary use the jquery datepicker. For me is the big anti-pattern. If you use angular2 this should promote full resource for development. I disappointed with it.

Comment: You leave your update as the answer for future people to know that its solved :)

Comment: I'm development datepicker custom for use this. After finishing post the link of github.

Comment: ngModel approach works, I'm using angular 6 version and this is the correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered what's problem. Angular2 ignore input with type="date". After change type for text works for me. The problem now is. For use one field as date is necessary use datepicker. I use material-design-lite as framework responsive. This not contains datepicker for fix this. Will be necessary use the jquery datepicker. For me is the big anti-pattern. If you use angular2 this should promote full resource for development. I disappointed with it.

For fix this, i used custom datepicker: https://github.com/emirdeliz/meus-projetos/tree/master/angular2-schedule/app/frontend/components/datepicker

Answer (score 4):

Sadly, `NgModel` does not work at this time for `input` of type `date`. I found a simple workaround however.

```
// In your HTML
<input #myDatePicker 
    type="date" 
    value='{{ myDate | date:"yyyy-MM-dd" }}' 
    (input)="onInput(myDatePicker.value)" />

// In your component (TypeScript):
public myDate: Date;

public onInput(value: Date): void{

    this.myDate = value;
}
```

This provides you with a way to set the value of your `myDate` property on your component. I personally prefer this over using someone's custom picker, thus incurring a dependency.

Answer (score 4):

`ngModel` does not work, but `ngModelChange` works for me:

```html
<input class="form-control" type="date" [ngModel]="myDate.value" 
       value="{{myDate.value | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" (ngModelChange)="myDate.value=$event">
```

Comment: Please check your double quotes, they are unbalanced.

Answer (score -1):

yes there is option for us to use

```
<input type="date" [(ngModel)]="company.birthdate"/>
```

for getting date for our project. but yes this is not compatible for the multi browser plateform (like mozila) and there are many cross browser library for the same.

I have made one stylish calendar Datepicker using Bootflat

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

hope this gives you more stylish and multi browser datepicker.